# Deleting set of XML record based on duplicate Element value

Tags: c#, sql, xml, linq, duplicates

I have the following XML file:

```xml
<RHL_IncentiveGroup>
  <ID>5eaaf7fd-68f5-430b-ade5-00ad1b952fc2</ID>
  <Name>Legacy_QReward_Sojos Cat 1lb</Name>
  <Description>Migrated from Q-Reward</Description>
  <RequirePermission>false</RequirePermission>
  <SyncGuid>0003d9cb-e39a-4fd1-bda6-d2608eb29d05</SyncGuid>
</RHL_IncentiveGroup>
<RHL_IncentiveGroup>
  <ID>0ab4f2d5-ad86-4e56-a6ce-00e1dacd041f</ID>
  <Name>Legacy_QReward_Sojos Cat 1lb</Name>
  <Description>Migrated from Q-Reward</Description>
  <RequirePermission>false</RequirePermission>
  <SyncGuid>000abbcf-2ef2-41ed-84fb-80de503e42b3</SyncGuid>
</RHL_IncentiveGroup>
<RHL_IncentiveGroup>
  <ID>bda6cc8b-3608-49e6-8720-024e6ee75434</ID>
  <Name>Legacy_QReward_TOW Dog 28lbs</Name>
  <Description>Migrated from Q-Reward</Description>
  <RequirePermission>false</RequirePermission>
  <SyncGuid>00096931-bc97-4f6d-8510-e6ccf63f6dc8</SyncGuid>
</RHL_IncentiveGroup>
```

I want to delete those `RHL_IncentiveGroup` nodes where the `Name` are identical and keep only one.

e.g. where `Name` is `Legacy_QReward_Sojos Cat 1lb`

Comment: What did you research, what is not working for you? Also you used the SQL tag, how does this relate to SQL ?

Comment: @AmritpalSingh Are you aware of the fact that is not a well-formed XML? Root element is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have the following object model into which you can deserialize the xml:

```cs
public class RHLIncentiveGroup
{
    [XmlElement(elementName:"ID")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool RequirePermission { get; set; }
    public Guid SyncGuid { get; set; }
}
```

In order to make your XML well-formed I've added a `<groups>` node to surround your `<RHL_IncentiveGroup>` elements. So, we have to create class for the top level node as well:

```cs
[XmlRoot("groups", Namespace = "")]
public class Groups
{
    [XmlElement("RHL_IncentiveGroup")]
    public List<RHLIncentiveGroup> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Let's deserialize the xml into a `Groups` class instance:

```cs
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(originalXml);
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Groups));
var withDuplicates = (Groups) serializer.Deserialize(doc.CreateReader());
```

Now, let's remove duplicates:

```cs
var withoutDuplicates = withDuplicates.Items
    .GroupBy(groupNode => groupNode.Name)
    .Select(nameGroupNodes => nameGroupNodes.First());
```

And finally serialize it back to xml:

```cs
var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);

var writer = new StringWriter();
serializer.Serialize(writer, withoutDuplicates, ns);

var updatedXml = writer.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

This gets complicated because you have multiple tags at root level.  Here is a solution using xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME, settings);

            List<XElement> RHLgroups = new List<XElement>();

            while (!reader.EOF)
            {
                if (reader.Name != "RHL_IncentiveGroup")
                {
                    reader.ReadToFollowing("RHL_IncentiveGroup");
                }
                if (!reader.EOF)
                {
                    RHLgroups.Add((XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader));
                }
            }

            var groups = RHLgroups
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Element("Name"))
                .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
                .ToList();
        
        }
      
 
    }

}
```

---

Easiest way to leave one is to copy into new list and the set original list to null.

```
           var groups = RHLgroups
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Element("Name"))
                .Select(x => XElement.Parse(x.FirstOrDefault().ToString()))
                .ToList();

            RHLgroups = null;
```

Comment: how do i delete the entire record including the childnodes?